# Posting HTML special character code in a form value

Tags: html, post, character-encoding

I'm supposed to post form data that contains non-English characters such as 'ü'. The accept-charset attribute worked well with Firefox and chrome but not with IE. So I decided to escape all non-English characters. For example I replaced any 'ü' character with its HTML code `&#252;`.

Now when I post the form, on any browser, the code `&#252;` is replaced with a funky string like 'Ã¼'. Why is it happening, is there a way to send form value without being changed?

Answer (score 3):

you should use `encodeUriComponent`. thats all.

before you post  - change the values ( by hidden or by exact value) the values by  using the JS function

encodeURIcomponent .

this will make your chars => utf8.

so you wont have a problem submitting them.

Answer (score 0):

Make the page containing the form UTF-8 encoding, declare that encoding properly, and make the server-side form handler process the UTF-8 data.

It’s difficult to say what went wrong with your previous attempts, but it’s more constructive to concentrate on implementing the right way. Using UTF-8 is the only way to ensure that all characters entered by the user are sent correctly.